# Postback, filters and sorting data in an App using Django and AJAX

Tags: python, jquery, mysql, django, ajax

I keep having this problem where I can't order some tables by date. I'm reading this code, I didn't write it so it will be useful if anyone can give me some tips. If I miss some information, just ask me, please.

The ListView code:

```py
def poll_ajax(request, poll_id,  user_url,  venue_id=None):
    cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
    start = request.GET['start']
    length = int(request.GET['length'])
    page = int(request.GET['draw'])

    poll = Poll.objects.get(id=poll_id)

    if not can_access_poll(request, poll):
        return JsonResponse({"error": "An error occurred"})

    date_from = None
    period = None
    date_condition_shown = ''
    if request.GET.get("period"):
        period = request.GET['period']
    if period and period != 'Total':
        date_condition, date_condition_shown, date_previous_condition, days_difference, date_from, date_to, filtering_by_date, date_from_previous, date_to_previous, date_from_string, date_from_previous_string = build_dates(
            period, None)

    if 'venue_id' in request.GET and request.GET['venue_id'] != '0' and request.GET['venue_id'] != 'undefined':
        filter_venue_id = request.GET['venue_id']
    elif venue_id:
        filter_venue_id = venue_id
    else:
        filter_venue_id = None

    try:
        total = PollUser.objects.filter(poll=poll, completed=True).count()

        query = 'Select v.shown_on, v.source, u.first_name, u.last_name, p.id, v.id, ve.name ' \
                'From app_polluser v ' \
                'Inner join app_customuser u on u.id = v.user_id ' \
                'Inner join app_userprofile p on p.user_id = u.id '

        query += 'Left join app_session s on v.session_id = s.id '
        query += 'Left join app_router r on s.router_id = r.id '
        query += 'Left join app_venue ve on r.venue_id = ve.id '

        query += 'Where v.completed = 1 and v.poll_id = ' + poll_id

        if filter_venue_id:
            query += ' and ve.id = ' + filter_venue_id

        if date_condition_shown != '':
            query += date_condition_shown
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        result = [(humanize_timesince(r[0]),
                  translate_source(r[1]),
                   (('<a href=\'/profile/%s/' + user_url + '\'>%s %s</a>') % (r[4], r[2], r[3])),
                   r[6],
                   r[5]) for r in result]

        result = [list(x[:4]) + get_votes(poll, x[4]) for x in result]

        total_filtered = total
        if filter_venue_id:
            count_filtered = 'Select Count(*) From app_polluser v '
            count_filtered += 'Left join app_session s on v.session_id = s.id '
            count_filtered += 'Left join app_router r on s.router_id = r.id '
            count_filtered += 'Where v.completed = 1 and v.poll_id = ' + poll_id + ' and r.venue_id = ' + filter_venue_id

            cursor.execute(count_filtered)
            total_filtered = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```

And the server response is this:

> "[02/Oct/2019 14:59:11]'GET
>   /poll_ajax/268/customer/33?period=Total&venue_id=0&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns..."
>   HTTP/1.1' 200 801"

If you have any advise, even if my post didn't bring many information, just tell me, I just want to know what is the problem here.

Additionaly the database that the app is using is in MySQL and is local.